# MSSQL server refusing connection through php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm working with and old web application that people of my work use in order to easily execute sql queries... it have worked for years until two weeks ago when someone where working opening ports and adding security to the servers (I'm not sure why)... and now we can't realice what is avoiding the webserver to connect to the SQL server.

I don't know so much about MS SQL server and ODBC (with is the engine used to connect) so I'm not sure how should I proceed now but I think all driver stuff should be propertly configured as it worked two weeks ago.

The error we get now is:

```
PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SSL Security error, SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in D:\Plesk\vhosts\saf.uab.cat\httpdocs\botonera\model\connect.php on line 4
```

The php code we use to connect to the data base:

```
function connect() {
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=************;Database=******", '********', '********');

            if (!$conn) {
            die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL.');
        }
        return $conn;
        }
?>
```

What should I check now?

thanks for the help

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server's logs to see if a connection attempt is being made, and if so, what are the errors for the failed connection attempt?

Comment: >>>SSL Security error<<< Your server now is configured foe encrypted connections, and your sonnection is not encrypter. You should either encrypt your connection or configure SQL Server not to use encryption

Comment: I'm not sure if it is as simple as this but I've tried to encrypt my connection adding to the connect code:  Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=false at the DNS string and nothing changes. Maybe I should do something else?

Comment: Did you install the certificate first? Check here for the detailes: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3299/how-to-configure-ssl-encryption-in-sql-server/

Comment: Did you find out what the issue is? I have one database that is actively refusing connection. when i change the .env to point to another server it works fine. when tracing from sql server, I see no login attempt.